# What is a good Javascript graphing library to use with GWT application?

Tags: javascript, gwt, graphing

Do you have any suggestions of graphing libraries to use with a GWT project? I need to graph a set of data points and several lines. Also some shading of the area under a line. I am open to suggestions of straight Javascript libraries or Java that I can just use with GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### D3.js

[gwt-d3](https://github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3) is a GWT wrapper library around the [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) library

### Google Visualization API

[Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en) has a [GWT binding](https://github.com/googlearchive/gwt-google-apis) which is no longer under active development

Comment: This project is no longer under development as of 2015 September.

Comment: @JoelHandwell Thanks! is there a replacement? If there is feel free to edit, I haven't used GWT in a very long time!

Comment: I would suggest gwt-d3, last commit is Jun 8, 2015, so we can safely say it's maintained. Though development is not super active.

Comment: Thanks, bumped up D3.j3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [GWT Highcharts](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/), a GWT wrapper of [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts/) library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Google Visualization API but just wanted to bring attention to:

raphaelGWT (http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/) 
Ext-GWT (http://www.extjs.com/products/gwt/)

Keep in mind not ALL of the Google Visualization charts are completely javascript (ie The Motion Chart which is flashed based).